# Duplicate node bug in dot (GraphViz)

Tags: dot

I have programmatically generated [this large .dot file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8286935/mygraphmatched.dot).

I compile it under Linux with

```
dot -Tps mygraphmatched.dot -o mygraphmatched.ps
```

However, the last node gets duplicated multiple times in the resulting graph (white circles in [the provided .ps image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8286935/mygraphmatched.ps)).

I have tried dot, sfdp, fdp, twopi.

I suspect a bug in the dot compiler, but a second opinion wouldn't hurt.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I removed all the individual node descriptions regarding label and merged node declarations into the resulting 5 different node type groups (regarding shape and fillcolor). This resolved the issue of duplicate nodes appearing, but I lose the individual label functionality, which was useful to me.

Comment: @george_zp  Though this is strange as the graphviz suite tools are used in many projects already and so it seems to me that such a basic bug would have been already found, you can always file a report at http://www.graphviz.org/content/graphviz-issue-tracker. You may also have more answers about how to solve it

Comment: I reported the bug. Now we wait.